# Java - Return random index of specific character in string

Tags: java, random

So given a string such as: `0100101`, I want to return a random single index of one of the positions of a `1` (1, 5, 6).

So far I'm using:

```
protected int getRandomBirthIndex(String s) {
        ArrayList<Integer> birthIndicies = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if ((s.charAt(i) == '1')) {
                birthIndicies.add(i);
            }
        }
        return birthIndicies.get(Randomizer.nextInt(birthIndicies.size()));
    }
```

However, it's causing a bottle-neck on my code (45% of CPU time is in this method), as the strings are over 4000 characters long. Can anyone think of a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: So far, both answers assume that you call the method multiple times with the same string. Is that the case?

Comment: No, so each call will be using a unique string 0.99975% of the time. However, the string object itself will be the same each time, it is modified between calls.

Comment: Since strings are immutable, the "string object" cannot be the *same* and modified between calls.

Comment: Are the strings always the same length, i.e., do they always use the same range of indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in a single index of one of the positions with `1`, and assuming there is at least one `1` in your input, you can just do this:

```
    String input = "0100101"; 
    final int n=input.length();
    Random generator = new Random();
    char c=0;
    int i=0;
    do{
        i = generator.nextInt(n);           
        c=input.charAt(i);
    }while(c!='1');
    System.out.println(i);
```

This solution is fast and does not consume much memory, for example when `1` and `0` are distributed uniformly. As highlighted by @paxdiablo it can perform poorly in some cases, for example when `1` are scarce.

Comment: Write `'1'`, not `49`. --- This will spin a lot if the occurrence of the letter is low, though it likely will be faster on average.

Comment: This is what I just figured out haha. Your code is slightly faster than my implementation however!

Comment: See my caution on hinneLinks's answer. Non-deterministic solutions can turn around and bite you in certain cases :-)

Comment: Actually, I've just had another thought, I think that makes three this year. It's going to perform *particularly* badly if the string has no `1` characters in it at all :-) The code in the question would throw IllegalArgumentException but this one would loop forever. It may be worth pointing this out or prechecking the string to ensure it has at least one `1` in it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String.indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) to find each `1` (instead of iterating every character). I would also prefer to program to the `List` interface and to use the diamond operator `<>`. Something like,

```
private static Random rand = new Random();
protected int getRandomBirthIndex(String s) {
    List<Integer> birthIndicies = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = s.indexOf('1');
    while (index > -1) {
        birthIndicies.add(index);
        index = s.indexOf('1', index + 1);
    }
    return birthIndicies.get(rand.nextInt(birthIndicies.size()));
}
```

Finally, if you need to do this many times, save the `List` as a field and re-use it (instead of calculating the indices every time). For example with [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization),

```
private static Random rand = new Random();
private static Map<String, List<Integer>> memo = new HashMap<>();

protected int getRandomBirthIndex(String s) {
    List<Integer> birthIndicies;
    if (!memo.containsKey(s)) {
        birthIndicies = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = s.indexOf('1');
        while (index > -1) {
            birthIndicies.add(index);
            index = s.indexOf('1', index + 1);
        }
        memo.put(s, birthIndicies);
    } else {
        birthIndicies = memo.get(s);
    }
    return birthIndicies.get(rand.nextInt(birthIndicies.size()));
}
```

Comment: Interestly (at least in my case), this is approximately as fast as my own method (yours is 1% faster). Memoization isn't helpful as a string would be  identical 0.00025% of the time! (Should have put that in my question sorry).

Answer (score 1):

Well, *one* way would be to remove the creation of the list each time, by caching the list based on the string itself, assuming the strings are used more often than they're changed. If they're not, then caching methods won't help.

The caching method involves, rather than having just a string, have an object consisting of:

- current string;
- cached string; and
- list based on the cached string.

You can provide a function to the clients to create such an object from a given string and it would set the string and the cached string to whatever was passed in, then calculate the list. Another function would be used to change the current string to something else.

The `getRandomBirthIndex()` function then receives this structure (rather than the string) and follows the rule set:

- if the current and cached strings are different, set the cached string to be the same as the current string, then recalculate the list based on that.
- in any case, return a random element from the list.

That way, if the list changes rarely, you avoid the expensive recalculation where it's not necessary.

In pseudo-code, something like this should suffice:

```python
# Constructs fastie from string.
# Sets cached string to something other than
# that passed in (lazy list creation).

def fastie.constructor(string s):
    me.current = s
    me.cached = s + "!"

# Changes current string in fastie. No list update in
# case you change it again before needing an element.

def fastie.changeString(string s):
    me.current = s

# Get a random index, will recalculate list first but
# only if necessary. Empty list returns index of -1.

def fastie.getRandomBirthIndex()
    me.recalcListFromCached()
    if me.list.size() == 0:
        return -1
    return me.list[random(me.list.size())]

# Recalculates the list from the current string.
# Done on an as-needed basis.

def fastie.recalcListFromCached():
    if me.current != me.cached:
        me.cached = me.current
        me.list = empty
        for idx = 0 to me.cached.length() - 1 inclusive:
            if me.cached[idx] == '1':
                me.list.append(idx)
```

You also have the option of speeding up the actual searching for the `1` character by, for example, useing [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%2C%20int%29) to locate them using the underlying Java libraries rather than checking each character individually in your own code (again, pseudo-code):

```python
def fastie.recalcListFromCached():
    if me.current != me.cached:
        me.cached = me.current
        me.list = empty
        idx = me.cached.indexOf('1')
        while idx != -1:
            me.list.append(idx)
            idx = me.cached.indexOf('1', idx + 1)
```

This method can be used even if you *don't* cache the values. It's likely to be faster using Java's probably-optimised string search code than doing it yourself.

---

However, you should keep in mind that your supposed problem of spending 45% of time in that code *may* not be an issue at all. It's not so much the proportion of time spent there as it is the absolute amount of time.

By that, I mean it probably makes no difference what percentage of the time being spent in that function if it finishes in 0.001 seconds (and you're not wanting to process thousands of strings per second). You should only really become concerned if the effects become noticeable to the user of your software somehow. Otherwise, optimisation is pretty much wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

If your Strings are very long *and* you're sure it contains a lot of 1s (or the String you're looking for), its probably faster to randomly "poke around" in the String until you find what you are looking for. So you save the time iterating the String:

```
String s = "0100101";
int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(s.length());

while(s.charAt(index) != '1') {
    System.out.println("got not a 1, trying again");
    index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(s.length());
}
System.out.println("found: " + index + " - " + s.charAt(index));
```

I'm not sure about the statistics, but it rare cases might happen that this Solution take much longer that the iterating solution. On case is a long String with only a very few occurrences of the search string.

If the Source-String doesn't contain the search String at all, this code will run forever!

Comment: I'm not a big fan of non-deterministic software. For a long string with only one `1` in it, this could take a very long time.

Comment: Yeah, but the requirement itself `return a random index` is not very deterministic itself.

Comment: Suggest you try with `String s = "00000";` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can even try this with best case complexity `O(1)` and in worst case it might go to `O(n)` or purely worst case can be infinity as it purely depends on `Randomizer` function that you are using.

```
private static Random rand = new Random(); 
protected int getRandomBirthIndex(String s) {
    List<Integer> birthIndicies = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = s.indexOf('1');
    while (index > -1) {
        birthIndicies.add(index);
        index = s.indexOf('1', index + 1);
    }
    return birthIndicies.get(rand.nextInt(birthIndicies.size())); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a short-circuited Fisher-Yates style shuffle.  Create an array of the `indices` and start shuffling it.  As soon as the next shuffled element points to a one, return that index.  If you find you've iterated through `indices` without finding a one, then this string contains only zeros so return -1.

If the length of the strings is always the same, the array `indices` can be `static` as shown below, and doesn't need reinitializing on new invocations.  If not, you'll have to move the declaration of `indices` into the method and initialize it each time with the correct index set.  The code below was written for strings of length 7, such as your example of `0100101`.

```
// delete this and uncomment below if string lengths vary
private static int[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

protected int getRandomBirthIndex(String s) {
   int tmp;
   /*
    * int[] indices = new int[s.length()];
    * for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) indices[i] = i;
    */
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      int j = randomizer.nextInt(indices.length - i) + i;
      if (j != i) {   // swap to shuffle
         tmp = indices[i];
         indices[i] = indices[j];
         indices[j] = tmp;
      }
      if ((s.charAt(indices[i]) == '1')) {
         return indices[i];
      }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

This approach terminates quickly if 1's are dense, guarantees termination after `s.length()` iterations even if there aren't any 1's, and the locations returned are uniform across the set of 1's.